# How to subsample a data frame based on a datetime column in R

Tags: r, datetime, subsampling

I would like to subsample a data frame at hourly intervals from a datetime column, beginning with the time value in the first row of the data frame. My data frame runs at 10-minute intervals from the first to the last row. Example data is below:

```
structure(list(datetime = structure(1:19, .Label = c("30/03/2011 05:09", 
"30/03/2011 05:19", "30/03/2011 05:29", "30/03/2011 05:39", "30/03/2011 05:49", 
"30/03/2011 05:59", "30/03/2011 06:09", "30/03/2011 06:19", "30/03/2011 06:29", 
"30/03/2011 06:39", "30/03/2011 06:49", "30/03/2011 06:59", "30/03/2011 07:09", 
"30/03/2011 07:19", "30/03/2011 07:29", "30/03/2011 07:39", "30/03/2011 07:49", 
"30/03/2011 07:59", "30/03/2011 08:09"), class = "factor"), a_count = c(66L, 
34L, 33L, 20L, 12L, 44L, 36L, 29L, 21L, 22L, 17L, 38L, 24L, 19L, 
60L, 54L, 27L, 36L, 45L), b_count = c(166.49, 167.54, 168.31, 
168.81, 169.24, 169.61, 169.96, 170.29, 170.63, 170.98, 171.31, 
171.62, 171.94, 172.29, 172.68, 173.15, 173.71, 174.34, 174.99
)), .Names = c("datetime", "a_count", "b_count"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

df

```
           datetime a_count b_count
1  30/09/2011 05:09      66  166.49
2  30/09/2011 05:19      34  167.54
3  30/09/2011 05:29      33  168.31
4  30/09/2011 05:39      20  168.81
5  30/09/2011 05:49      12  169.24
6  30/09/2011 05:59      44  169.61
7  30/09/2011 06:09      36  169.96
8  30/09/2011 06:19      29  170.29
9  30/09/2011 06:29      21  170.63
10 30/09/2011 06:39      22  170.98
11 30/09/2011 06:49      17  171.31
12 30/09/2011 06:59      38  171.62
13 30/09/2011 07:09      24  171.94
14 30/09/2011 07:19      19  172.29
15 30/09/2011 07:29      60  172.68
16 30/09/2011 07:39      54  173.15
17 30/09/2011 07:49      27  173.71
18 30/09/2011 07:59      36  174.34
19 30/09/2011 08:09      45  174.99
```

I would like to end up with the following data frame:

```
        datetime   a_count b_count
30/09/2011 05:09       66  166.49
30/09/2011 06:09       36  169.96
30/09/2011 07:09       24  171.94
30/09/2011 08:09       45  174.99
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is hard to guess what structure you have. Is it guaranteed that you have one value at exactly the first time value + x times 60 minutes? What happens if the value can not be found? What happens if you have two values at that time. Do you need approximate matching? Say, 09:10 is counted as 09:09?

On idea to get you started is the following:

```
# I will call your dataframe `d`. 
# Transform datetime to a POSIXct object, R's datatype for timestamps
d$datetime <- as.POSIXct(as.character(d$datetime), format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
# Extract the minutes
d$minute <- as.numeric(format(d$datetime, '%M'))
# And select by identical minute.
subset(d, minute == d$minute[1])
```

Comment: @ Thilo: This is exactly what I was look for. Many thanks! My data runs at exact 10-minute intervals from the first to the last row of the data frame. I will update the question. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
> df$datetime <- strptime(df$datetime, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")                                                                                                                                                                           
> df$dif <- c(0, cumsum(as.numeric(diff(df$datetime))))                                                                                                                                                                                     
>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
> df[df$dif %% 60 == 0,]                                                                                                                                                                                                              

               datetime a_count b_count dif
  2011-03-30 05:09:00      66  166.49   0
  2011-03-30 06:09:00      36  169.96  60
  2011-03-30 07:09:00      24  171.94 120
  2011-03-30 08:09:00      45  174.99 180
```

I have the same questions as Thilo, but heres another solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the lubridate packages to change the format of your times which may be a bit more intutitive and easy to remember.

Also, you can add variables based on the hour, and then summarize how you would like with plyr.

in the example below I took the sum and mean of a_count. May need to vary based on your purpose.

```
library(plyr)
library(lubridate)

df2 <- mutate(df, dt = dmy_hm(as.character(datetime)), hour = hour(dt), minute = minute(dt))
summary <- ddply(df2, .(hour), summarize, a_mean = mean(a_count), a_sum = sum(a_count))
```